# How can I use solc solidity compiler on truffle webpack?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, truffle, solc

When I try to import solc, it raises an error which says:

```
ERROR in ./~/require-from-string/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\users\bisrat\Desktop\webpacksample\node_modules\require-from-stri
ng'
 @ ./~/require-from-string/index.js 3:13-30
 @ ./~/solc/wrapper.js
 @ ./~/solc/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/javascripts/app.js
```

Comment: Share the steps you followed to install truffle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a webpack issue. Try adding target: 'node', to your webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: './app/javascripts/app.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  }
```